# Flutter MacOS get LogicalKeyboardKey for CMD

Tags: macos, flutter, dart

I'm building an app that heavily relies on keybindings. Right now, Flutter supports a ton of keybindings, and declaring a LogicalKeySet is very simple:

```
 final exampleKeySet = LogicalKeySet(
    LogicalKeyboardKey.control,
    LogicalKeyboardKey.comma,
  );
```

The `LogicalKeyboardKey` has a value for almost every key on the keyboard including the Ctrl and Alt Keys. But there is no option for a Command key on Mac.

How can I use the Command key with `LogicalKeySet`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After digging through the source code and using `RawKeyboardListener` to examine the "opaque" code of the CMD key, I discovered that LogicalKeyboard key **does** have a key for cmd which is `LogicalKeyboardKey.meta`.